# how to clip text in css like gmail does to emails subject listings

Tags: html, css

in gmail, they display the

subject - followed by a short snippet from the body

and it looks like the body text is clipped, i am assuming this is done with css, gmail style sheets are fairly complex, so am not certain

anyway only parts of letters are showing at the end of the line where they get chopped off

does anyone know how i can achieve the same effect, so i get full length text in a column

---

got it sussed thanks @cletus

just to clarify, this is what i ended up with

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 20px;">mytitle<span style="color: gray; "> - my long description goes here</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `overflow: hidden` CSS on block elements. The block-level element part is important. See [The CSS Overflow Property](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/).

Comment: so i just gave this a go <div style="overflow: hidden;">mytitle<span style="color: gray; "> - my long description goes here</span></div>, but it has multiple lines instead of clipping, am i doing it right ?

Comment: If you want help with an example I suggest you either post it here or post it as a new question. Comments aren't a great way of doing that. The link I posted has lots of examples so I suggest you look at those too, particularly the demos page http://css-tricks.com/examples/OverflowExample/

Comment: This only works if your div is fixed width. Gmail is not fixed. All the columns are fixed width except for the Subject column which is auto. This doesn't work when your table is 100% like gmail and when only one column is set to auto while the others are fixed.  

Anyone know how gmail does it?

Answer (score 8):

To get the full text-clipping effect, where only parts of letters show at the end of the element, just add:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one won't work in IE6-7. Use text-overflow css property instead. More about it: http://www.blakems.com/archives/000077.html (this won't validate! Validator notices, that it's a css3 property which doesn't exists in css2.1...)